# DocuSign embedded sending closes

Tags: docusignapi

Our client is experiencing some sporadic problems with the embedded sending window - very occasionally it will attempt to load but then fail as the progress bar underneath the DocuSign logo approaches completion.  We also see the following errors when we inspect the console window from Chrome or Edge:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://app.docusign.com/api/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/envelopes/XXXXXXXXXX/lock?cachebuster=0.9774476769958655

Angular > API Request Error [object Object]

vendor-a254e30b78.bundle.js (81,117215)

[object Object]: {end: "Mon Apr 09 2018 10:40:02 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)", errorKey: "EDIT_LOCK_ENVELOPE_NOT_LOCKED", errorMessage: "The envelope is not locked.", host: "https://app.docusign.com", payload: undefined...}

Unhandled promise rejection Error: Request failed with status code 404


vendor-a254e30b78.bundle.js (1,339010)

[object Error]: {config: Object, description: "Request failed with status code 404", message: "Request failed with status code 404", request: Object, response: Object...}
```

Finally, while attempting to investigate this I received the following 500 error on the DocuSign admin screen, which unfortunately customer services have been unable to assist with:

```
Error on Docusign site: 500 error. Transaction Id: T34364871276903272031
```

If anybody's got ANY insights into what might be going on I'd really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: Please contact DocuSign support to report the problem. A reproducible test case would be very helpful. Tell them that you are a developer building an integration.

Comment: I tried that before I posted here unfortunately, Larry.  Your customer service representatives are far from helpful when it comes to technical issues.  :(  I have however established that the issue happens when an excel document that contains a linked data source is uploaded.  As soon as the link was removed it was handled with no problems.

Comment: @LarryK, it appears that we've spoken previously on another integrations issue - do you mind if I email you or the API helpdesk with the sample file?

Comment: You're welcome to email me: larry.kluger at my company.com (DocuSign)